# How to Break knockout view model in parts with requirejs

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, structure

I am currently working on an application which is enlarging itself due to so much functionality. Here i am going to present some sample code to understand.

```
function test(){
    var self = this
    /*  Define Properties   */
    self.TaskSection = ko.observable()
    .
    .
    /*  Define Get Requrest */
    self.GetTasks = function(){

    }
    .
    .
    /*  Define Post Requrest    */
    self.PostTask  = function(){

    }
    .
    .

    /*  Define Helper Methods   */
    self.FormatDate  = function(){

    }   
    .
    .
    /*  Define Navigation Methods   */
    self.HomePage  = function(){

    }   
    .
    .
    /*  End */
}
```

OK. Pretty simple. You can see the sample model but it is now difficult to work with it as each section contains many functions. Lets assume more then 10 functions in each section. Now I want to manage the application using `requirejs`. This is what i have tried.

`The Structure`

```
app/
    js/
        /Collections/   /*  For ObservableArrays    */
        /Events/        /*  For Collections and Models  */
        /Helpers/       /*  For Collections and Models  */
        /Models/        /*  Default Properties  */
```

Currently what I want is now break the model in 3 to 4 parts.

- Collection.js where I define only `observableArray()`
- Events.js where I want to define server related functions
- Helpers.js where I want to define functions to do some internal work.

How can I achieve this. This is what I have tried.

```
define(["knockout"],function (ko) {
    function test(){
        var self = this
        self.TaskList = ko.observanleArray()
    }
    return new test()
});

define(["knockout","TaskList"],function (ko,TaskList) {
    var events  = function() {
        var self = this
        self.AddItem = function (data) {
            TaskList.push(TaskModel)
        }
        self.RemoveItem = function (data) {
            TaskList.remove(data)
        }
    }
    return new events()
});

define(["knockout","TaskList"],function (ko,TaskList) {
    var helpers  = function() {
        var self = this
        self.SortTaskList = function (data) {
            TaskList.sort()
        }
    }
    return new helpers()
});
```

Here I dont know how to merge them. `TaskList` in events.js and helper.js is undefined. I know I need to pass TaskList as parameter but I don't want to use function way. Instead I want to use literal way to merge these two files into Tasklist.js viewmodel.

How can I do this?

Comment: The next version of knockout 3.2 will help with this. It's worth watching this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/

Comment: I know it's not explicitly what you are asking for, but have you considered using inheritance? For example, you could have a base view model that defines common internal functions or events and then have your primary view model inherit from it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. for this i have already written two blog posts [here](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/knockoutjs-make-parent-and-child-structure-in-your-app/) and [here](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/with-binding-magic-writing-single-page-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-knockoutjs/) but the problem is that when a viewmodel gets lengthy i want to manage it using the technique i am asking above.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is an example of what you can do (this is an example, in real life you would split into separate js files):

Define ko as a module (not so useful as it is, you could remove the reference to "knockout")

```
define("knockout", function () {
    return ko;
});
```

Define a module for the TaskList

```
define("TaskList", ["knockout"],function (ko) {
    function TaskList(){
        var self = this;
        self.NameInput = ko.observable("");
        self.DescInput = ko.observable("");
        self.TaskList = ko.observableArray();
    }
    return new TaskList();
});
```

Define a module for the Events and reference the TaskList

```
define("Events", ["knockout","TaskList"],function (ko, obj) {
    var events  = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.AddItem = function (data) {
            var inputData;
            if (typeof(data.Name) === 'undefined') {
                inputData = { Name: obj.NameInput(), 
                              Description:  obj.DescInput() };
            } else
                inputData = data;
            obj.TaskList.push(inputData);
        }
        self.RemoveItem = function (data) {
            obj.TaskList.remove(data);
        }
    }
    return new events();
});
```

Define a module for the Helpers that also references the TaskList

```
define("Helpers", ["knockout","TaskList"],function (ko, obj) {
    var helpers  = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.SortTaskList = function (data) {
            obj.TaskList.sort();
        }
    }
    return new helpers();
});
```

Define a main module that will put all modules together

```
define("Main", ["knockout","TaskList", "Events", "Helpers"], 
       function (ko, obj, e, h) {
    var main  = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.Tasks = obj;
        self.Events = e;
        self.Helpers = h;
    }
    return new main();
});
```

Finally, call the main module and try to add an Item to the TaskList through the Events module

```
require(["Main", "knockout"], function (main, ko) {
   main.Events.AddItem({ Name: "My first task", Description: "Start the job"});
   main.Events.AddItem({ Name:"My second task", Description:"Continue the job"});
   main.Events.AddItem({ Name: "My last task", Description: "Finish the job"});
   ko.applyBindings(main);
   console.log(main.Tasks.TaskList().length);
});
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/d4R87/4/)

Comment: i have cheked this exaple but it is not working. Dependencies are not even loadig

Comment: @raheelshan Check your console, you should see "1", don't you?

Comment: @raheelshan I updated the code and fiddle to have a better example

Answer (score 3):

One thing to consider here is that require.js doesn't just want you to make modules within a single JavaScript file, it wants you to break the modules out into separate *files* to keep the modules from getting oversized.  The problem you are running in to is that you don't have any way of naming your modules currently so that the others know about them.  Consider this -

Tasklist.js

```
define(["knockout"],function (ko) {
    function test() {
        var self = this;
        self.TaskList = ko.observableArray();
    };
    return new test();
});
```

Events.js

```
define(["knockout","app/TaskList"],function (ko,TaskList) {
    var events  = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.AddItem = function (data) {
            TaskList.push(TaskModel);
        };
        self.RemoveItem = function (data) {
            TaskList.remove(data);
        };
    }
    return new events();
});
```

Helpers.js

```
define(["knockout","app/TaskList"],function (ko,TaskList) {
    var helpers = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.SortTaskList = function (data) {
            TaskList.sort();
        };
    }
    return new helpers();
});
```

Of course this assumes you already have a main.js or some entry point with require.js configuration set up to let require know *where* to find the files.  If you don't have that it would look something like this -

Main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
```

Which assumes you have something along the lines of this for your file structure -

(project dir)
  /app/
  Main.js
  Events.js
  TaskList.js
  Helpers.js

Now when you load require.js in your html file and point to main.js as the entry point all of your modules will be loaded.

Comment: I had already tried what you presented here. The problem is that `Events.js` says `TaskList` is `undefined`. I assume thats because `Event.js` need `TaskList` as parameter.

Comment: the other thing is that where ever i use `Tasklist.js` is lacks Events and helpers because Tasklist.js is not dependant both of them

Comment: I will update the define statements to include the app/ parameter but I know this method works as I am using it now

Comment: Sure i will try and let you know

Comment: Helpers is not required by any of your modules so it will never be loaded.  Tasklist, as you show it, is basically a stand alone module that holds a model.  If you want to require events from tasklist and tasklist from events then you need to either switch to using a parent module to require the two or use a two-way approach which is to `require()` one of the modules from within the other *after* it is loaded as mentioned on the require.js docs, as neither would be fully loaded until the other is which is a recursive situation.