# Can I test KnockOut ViewModel on Cucumberjs

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, bdd, cucumberjs

I've defined the following feature

```
Feature: Shoper can add an item to ShoppingCart

  Scenario: First item added to ShoppingCart
    Given I have an Empty ShoppingCart
    When I add an Item to ShoppingCart
    Then The ShoppingCart must have 1 item

  Scenario: Second item added to ShoppingCart
    Given I already have 1 item on my ShoppingCart
    When I add a second item to ShoppingCart
    Then The ShoppingCart must have 2 items
```

and used the CucumberJs to generate step definitions, as below:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function () {
  this.Given(/^I have an Empty ShoppingCart$/, function (callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback.pending();
  });

  this.When(/^I add an Item to ShoppingCart$/, function (callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback.pending();
  });

  this.Then(/^The ShoppingCart must have (\d+) item$/, function (arg1, callback) {

    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback.pending();
  });
}
```

but I didn't find a way to create an instance for my observable view model to test it there

```
function ShopCartViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
            total += item.price();
        });

        return total.toFixed(2);
    }, this);

    self.getItemFromList    = function ( id ) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function (item)
        {
            if (item.ProductId() === id()) {
                return item;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried to load knockout and after load my viewmodel:

```
  var ko = require('../../js/knockout-3.1.0');  
  var ShopCart = require('../../js/shopCartViewModel');

  var cart;

  console.log('ko :', ko); // <-defined
  console.log('cart :', ShopCart); // <- empty object {}

  this.Given(/^I have an Empty ShoppingCart$/, function (callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    cart = new ShopCart(); // <- error
    callback.pending();
  });
```

ko worked, but ShopCart returns `{}`

How can I create an instance for a  `ViewModel` inside CucumberJs step definitions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try with the [before hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#before-hooks)? Any luck?

Comment: @GôTô The before can handle the create but i didn't find a way to start the ko global on cucumber for the view model. ko is always `undefined`

Comment: How and when do you define ko?

Comment: @GôTô ko is defined by KnockoutJs. I just need to initialize the KnockOut framework on Cucumber

Comment: Yes, I understand that ko is from knockout. But how do you add the reference? Do you use requirejs? Do you have a `script` tag (where?)?

Comment: @GôTô Thais exactly what I need, I've tried to user node's require to load knockout but it didn't created the global ko. and when I required my viewmodel it returns undefined. I'm quite a newbie in JS don't know if i used called it the right way. Want me to post my tries that didn't work?

Comment: Yes, if you could post you tries, and more info about how you start this cucumber stuff

Comment: @GôTô , that is the closest try I've got

Comment: Are you sure you return something in `shopCartViewModel`?

Comment: it is an object that needs to be created as new shopCarViewModel, does it need to return something?

Comment: Well with requirejs you need to `define` and return your object. Check [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281426/how-to-break-knockout-view-model-in-parts-with-requirejs/24492929#24492929) or [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/)

Comment: @GôTô Very nice example. I will try it when I get home today and post a feedback here.

Comment: @GôTô I've managed to do all the changes to work with requireJS, and installed require for node. Now I believe I just need to do the node requires. But this weekend were my college tests. Sorry for the delay. Around the lunch time i will stop to do the test. Thanks

Comment: @GôTô It worked installing requirejs on node and configuring my knockout to work with require. Thaks a lot. If you elaborate some answer I will reward you for sure. Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, was needed to use [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/) on both, FrontEnd and Cucumber

### Front-End

Download RequireJS and put it into your scripts folder

Create a `main.js` or `init.js`, it is the file that will define and require your FrontEnd modules async

```
require(['knockout-3.1.0', 'appViewModel'], function(ko, appViewModel) {
    ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
});
```

crie seu viewModel utilizando a função define do requireJS

```
define(['knockout-3.1.0', 'shopCartItemViewModel'], function (ko, ShopCartItem) {
    return function ShopCart() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
            var total = 0;

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function(item) {
                total += parseFloat(item.NetValue());
            });

            return total;
        }, self.items);
    }
});
```

In the front end, let RequireJs load your modules async

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

### For cucumber

Install `RequireJs` with npm

```
npm install requirejs -g
```

Create another main file, this time for node, since there is some differences smeantic differences

*file: main_node.js*

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs(['knockout-3.1.0', 'shopCartViewModel' /*, 'appViewModel'*/], function(ko, shopCartViewModel) {
    //ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
});
```

Now, your just need to initialize requireJs on your cucmber step definition or in a before hook for all tests

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function () {

    var assert = require('assert');
    var requirejs = require('requirejs');    
    var item = function (itemId) {
        return {
            id : itemId,
            nome: "Cookie " + itemId,
            itemQtd: 1,
            valorUnitario: 3.00,
            tipo: "Cookie",
            unitDiscount: 0.4
        }
    }

    requirejs.config({
      //path for your js files
      baseUrl: __dirname + '\\..\\..\\js',
      //Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
      //function to requirejs so that node modules
      //are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
      nodeRequire: require('../../js/main_node')
    });

    var ShopCart = requirejs('shopCartViewModel');

    var cart;

    this.Given(/^I have an Empty ShoppingCart$/, function (callback) {

        cart = new ShopCart();
        cart.items.removeAll();
        callback();
    });

    this.When(/^I add an Item to ShoppingCart$/, function (callback) {

        cart.addItemToCart(item(1));
        callback();
    });

    this.Then(/^The ShoppingCart must have (\d+) items$/, function (cartItemsCount, callback) {

        assert.equal(cart.getItemsCount(), cartItemsCount, 'ShopCart should have ' + cartItemsCount + ' items but have ' + cart.getItemsCount());
        callback();
    });

    this.Given(/^I already have (\d+) items on my ShoppingCart$/, function (itemsCount, callback) {

        cart.items.removeAll();
        for (i = 1; i <= itemsCount; i++) {
            (function (j) {
                cart.addItemToCart(item(j));
            }(i));
        }
        callback();
    });

    this.When(/^I add a second item to ShoppingCart$/, function (callback) {
        cart.addItemToCart(item(2));
        callback();
    });

    this.When(/^I add quantity of (\d+) to the first item$/, function (incrementCount, callback) {
        var itemFromCart = cart.getItemFromList(1);
        cart.addToItem(itemFromCart, incrementCount);
        callback();
    });

    this.Then(/^The first item must have a quantity of (\d+)$/, function (expectedItemCount, callback) {
        var itemFromCart = cart.getItemFromList(1);
        assert.equal(itemFromCart.quantidade(), expectedItemCount, 'Should have ' + expectedItemCount + ' items but have ' + itemFromCart.quantidade());
        callback();
    });

    this.When(/^I add (\d+) items to ShoppingCart$/, function (itemsCount, callback) {
        for (i = 1; i <= itemsCount; i++) {
            (function (j) {
                cart.addItemToCart(item(j));
            }(i));
        }
        callback();
    });

    this.Then(/^Shopping cart must have (\d+) value$/, function (netValue, callback) {
        console.log(cart.grandTotal());
        assert.equal(parseFloat(cart.grandTotal()), netValue, 'Total must be ' + netValue + ' but was ' + parseFloat(cart.grandTotal()));
        callback();
    });
}
```

### Final Result

```
D:\Private\node\Projetos\siteBiscoitaria\public_www>cucumber-js
............

4 scenarios (4 passed)
12 steps (12 passed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs) to load both knockout and your viewmodel.

Use `define` like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281426/how-to-break-knockout-view-model-in-parts-with-requirejs/24492929#24492929):

```
define("Main", ["knockout","TaskList", "Events", "Helpers"], 
       function (ko, obj, e, h) {
    var main  = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.Tasks = obj;
        self.Events = e;
        self.Helpers = h;
    }
    return new main(); //<= very important to return an object
});
```

You can also check [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/).